# Loading a file into MYSQL table error code 1062 Duplicate entry for primary key

Tags: mysql, csv

The table is empty before load statement is executed
do a `select * from code_protocol;`
only entry is line with null values for all columns/fields

To test the error I created from excel by saving a comma delimited *.csv file

The csv file has only one entry/row and I am only loading primary key and one other column.

```
load data infile 'c:/wamp64/tmp/code_protocol1.csv'
into table code_protocol
FIELDS terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 rows
(protocol_id, protocol_disc
);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please show your table design AND your csv. This is usually the case when defining a primary index w/o autoindex and the according column is not set in the CSV, MySQL is trying to add a null value for a primary index col then.

Comment: It was a data problem, I created the file using excel and saved it as a csv file.

Comment: I opened the saved file with a text editor and it showed I had a bunch of empty extra rows that were being saved